# How to connect to Google Cloud RabbitMQ from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, rabbitmq, google-cloud-platform

I have rabbitMQ running as a VM inside a Google Cloud Project. In that same project I have a NodeJS app running in which I am trying to connect to rabbitMQ.

I keep getting the error:

```
[AMQP] connect ETIMEDOUT ip:port
```

I think its because in the firewall settings there is specified an allowed IP Range of 0.0.0.0/0.

How would I specify that my NodeJS App is also allowed access?

I have also allowed tcp protocoll on the relevant ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason I wasnt able to connect was because I hadn't even deployed the GAE App, rather I tested it with a simple `npm start` inside of the Google Cloud Shell. As soon as I deployed and connected to the rabbitMQ instance over its internal IP it worked like a charm.